# Specify an argument to make it default

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I have in my code a dictionary of flags to add as a new argument to argparser. It is in a separate dict because I will need the help text later.

Some arguments need to be passed for `parser.add_argument`, but sometimes they don't. So if they don't need to be passed, they are equal to `None` in the dict. However, if I try to pass `None`, it will consider that's a new argument. How can I make the code don't pass the specified argument if it is equal to `None`?

```
parser_arguments = {
    "--version" : {
        "alias" : "-V",
        "action" : "store_true",
        "help" : "Show Red's current version",
        "nargs" : None,
        "type" : None,
        "default" : None
    },
    "--list-instances" : {
        "alias" : None,
        "action" : "store_true",
        "help" : "List all instance names setup with 'redbot-setup'",
        "nargs" : None,
        "type" : None,
        "default" : None
    },
    "--owner" : {
        "alias" : None,
        "action" : "store_true",
        "help" : "ID of the owner. Only who hosts "
                "Red should be owner, this has "
                "serious security implications if misused.",
        "nargs" : None,
        "type" : None,
        "default" : None
    },
    "--co-owner" : {
        "alias" : None,
        "action" : "store_true",
        "help" : "ID of a co-owner. Only people who have access "
                "to the system that is hosting Red should be  "
                "co-owners, as this gives them complete access "
                "to the system's data. This has serious "
                "security implications if misused. Can be "
                "multiple.",
        "nargs" : "*",
        "type" : int,
        "default" : []
    },
    "--prefix" : {
        "alias" : "-p",
        "action" : "append",
        "help" : "Global prefix. Can be multiple",
        "nargs" : None,
        "type" : None,
        "default" : None
    }
}

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Red - Discord Bot",
                                 usage="redbot <instance_name> [arguments]")
for argument in parse_arguments:
    parser.add_argument(argument, argument["alias"], action=argument["action"], help=argument["help"], nargs=argument["nargs"], type=argument["type"], default=argument["default"]
```

I already though about making the argument in the dict be the default one, but it is not specified in the [API reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-add-argument-method)

Comment: The best way would probably be to match the structure of the dictionary with the actual arguments' names, then just do `.add_argument(*positional, **keyword)`. Then for those that don't need a given parameter, just leave it out.

Comment: You need to change the `action` for 'co-owner' to `None` or 'store'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A helper function to strip out the `None`:

```
def foo(adic):
    newdic = {k:v for k,v in adic.items() if v is not None}
    try:
        alias = newdic.pop('alias')
    except KeyError:
        pass
    return newdic
```

e.g.  `co-owner` with the correction I noted in the comment

```
In [114]: foo(parser_arguments['--co-owner'])
Out[114]: 
{'default': [],
 'help': "ID of a co-owner. Only people who have access to the system that is hosting Red should be  co-owners, as this gives them complete access to the system's data. This has serious security implications if misused. Can be multiple.",
 'nargs': '*',
 'type': int}

In [115]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [116]: for k, v in parser_arguments.items():
     ...:     args = [a for a in [v['alias']] if a is not None]
     ...:     parser.add_argument(k, *args, **foo(v))
     ...:   

In [117]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--version] [--list-instances] [--owner]
                [--co-owner [CO_OWNER [CO_OWNER ...]]] [--prefix PREFIX]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --version, -V         Show Red's current version
  --list-instances      List all instance names setup with 'redbot-setup'
  --owner               ID of the owner. Only who hosts Red should be owner,
                        this has serious security implications if misused.
  --co-owner [CO_OWNER [CO_OWNER ...]]
                        ID of a co-owner. Only people who have access to the
                        system that is hosting Red should be co-owners, as
                        this gives them complete access to the system's data.
                        This has serious security implications if misused. Can
                        be multiple.
  --prefix PREFIX, -p PREFIX
                        Global prefix. Can be multiple
```

`add_argument` returns the `Action` object that you just created.  Some of its attributes can be viewed and even modified.  It may be handy to collect your own list of those objects.  Or you can view them after creation with:

```
In [118]: parser._actions
Out[118]: 
[_HelpAction(option_strings=['-h', '--help'], dest='help', nargs=0, const=None, default='==SUPPRESS==', type=None, choices=None, help='show this help message and exit', metavar=None),
 _StoreTrueAction(option_strings=['--version', '-V'], dest='version', nargs=0, const=True, default=False, type=None, choices=None, help="Show Red's current version", metavar=None),
 _StoreTrueAction(option_strings=['--list-instances'], dest='list_instances', nargs=0, const=True, default=False, type=None, choices=None, help="List all instance names setup with 'redbot-setup'", metavar=None),
 _StoreTrueAction(option_strings=['--owner'], dest='owner', nargs=0, const=True, default=False, type=None, choices=None, help='ID of the owner. Only who hosts Red should be owner, this has serious security implications if misused.', metavar=None),
 _StoreAction(option_strings=['--co-owner'], dest='co_owner', nargs='*', const=None, default=[], type=<class 'int'>, choices=None, help="ID of a co-owner. Only people who have access to the system that is hosting Red should be  co-owners, as this gives them complete access to the system's data. This has serious security implications if misused. Can be multiple.", metavar=None),
 _AppendAction(option_strings=['--prefix', '-p'], dest='prefix', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help='Global prefix. Can be multiple', metavar=None)]
```

That way you can see how the input parameters translate into the attributes that control parsing and the help print.